# tradingview pinescript 15min data on 1sec chart cannot use mutable variable in security function as an argument

Tags: pine-script

I need to use this indicator on 1sec chart with data from 15min chart.
I tried using security function, but this give me this error: Cannot use a mutable variable as an argument of the security function"

```
//@version=4

////////
// Fetch Ingredients 
// [
Depth       = input(7, "Depth", input.integer, minval=1, step=1)
Deviation   = input(5, "Deviation", input.integer, minval=1, step=1)
Backstep    = input(2, "Backstep", input.integer, minval=2, step=1)
line_thick  = input(2, "Line Thickness", input.integer, minval=1, maxval=4)
upcolor     = input(color.lime, "Bull Color")
dncolor     = input(color.red, "Bear Color")
repaint     = input(true, "Repaint Levels")
// ]


//////// 
// Bake
// [
var last_h = 1, last_h := last_h + 1
var last_l = 1, last_l := last_l + 1
var lw = 1, var hg = 1
lw := lw + 1, hg := hg + 1
p_lw = -lowestbars(Depth), p_hg = -highestbars(Depth)
lowing = lw == p_lw or low - low[p_lw] > Deviation*syminfo.mintick
highing = hg == p_hg or high[p_hg] - high > Deviation*syminfo.mintick
lh = barssince(not highing[1]), ll = barssince(not lowing[1])
down = barssince(not (lh > ll)) >= Backstep, lower = low[lw] > low[p_lw], higher = high[hg] < high[p_hg]
if lw != p_lw and (not down[1] or lower)
    lw := p_lw < hg ? p_lw : 0
if hg != p_hg and (down[1] or higher)
    hg := p_hg < lw ? p_hg : 0

line zz = na
label point = na
x1 = down ? lw : hg
y1 = down ? low[lw] : high[hg]

if down == down[1]
    if repaint
        label.delete(point[1])
        line.delete(zz[1])
    down
if down != down[1]
    if down
        last_h := hg
    else
        last_l := lw
    if not repaint
        nx = down?last_h:last_l
        zz := line.new(bar_index-nx, down ? high[nx] : low[nx], bar_index-(down?last_l:last_h), down ? low[last_l] : high[last_h], width=line_thick, color=down?upcolor:dncolor)
        point := label.new(bar_index-nx, down ? high[nx] : low[nx], down ? (high[nx] > high[last_h[1]]?"HH":"LH") : (low[nx] < low[last_l[1]] ? "LL" : "HL"), style=down?label.style_label_down:label.style_label_up, size=size.tiny, color=down?dncolor:upcolor, textcolor=color.black, tooltip = down ? (high[nx] > high[last_h[1]]?"Higher High":"Lower High") : (low[nx] < low[last_l[1]] ? "Lower Low" : "Higher Low"))
    down
if repaint
    zz := line.new(bar_index-(down?last_h:last_l), down ? high[last_h] : low[last_l], bar_index-x1, y1, width=line_thick, color=down?dncolor:upcolor)
    point := label.new(bar_index-x1, y1, down ? (low[x1] < low[last_l] ? "LL" : "HL") : (high[x1] > high[last_h]?"HH":"LH"), style=down?label.style_label_up:label.style_label_down, size=size.tiny, color=down?upcolor:dncolor, textcolor=color.black, tooltip = down ? (low[x1] < low[last_l] ? "Lower Low" : "Higher Low") : (high[x1] > high[last_h]?"Higher High":"Lower High"))
// ]
```

What I really need is only this logic from the indicator

```
low[x1] > low[last_l]
```

I can't simply change depth from 7 to 6300 to get the results what I want, because this is too many candles to process.
So I tried using security function, but can't get this to work.

I will be really grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues at play here:

1. The `last_l` variable is a mutable (it's reassigned with `:=`) so its calculation would need to be encapsulated in a function which then could be called with `security()`.
2. This is the most important issue. It's that you are calculating bar offsets, yet bar offsets at a HTF cannot be translated at the chart's timeframe. What does an offset of 10 bars at 15min mean at 1S? It's impossible to tell because there will be a varying number of bars in the 1S dilation of the 15min TF at the chart's resolution.

Scripts like MTF Ichimokus or pivot scripts always run into issue #2. There is no perfect way to resolve this conundrum. [This MTF pivot script](https://www.tradingview.com/script/VYzEUnYB-Pivots-MTF-LucF/) shows how you can lookback in the chart's past bars to look for the closest value of a pivot value identified in a HTF. It's a compromise that may not work for all situations.

Comment: Thanks for your indicator. It's great, shows last low just like the ZigZag and with right settings works in 1s chart. I think I can make it work in my strategy.

Big thanks again, this will save some money for me.